# A true wireless alternative for the Logitech K740 keyboard

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth, wireless, logitech

I've always used full sized keyboards, with high profile keys. (I'm a developer)
I think it's time to make some changes.

Today I went to a big computer shop. Tried out many keyboards. Mainly from Logitech and Microsoft. I even tried some  gaming keyboards, but I was very disappointed with how they all felt. Except one! The Logitech K740. This keyboard really stood out. It has very low profiles keys, right spacing between the keys, big keys, a little bend/curving in the keys like on traditional keyboards and illuminated keys. It just felt right. By the way is was also the best looking keyboard of all off them.

Only one problem it was not wireless. Something I'm really want right now. Ideally with Bluetooth support. Even beter, multiple channels like the Logitech MX Master mouse would be great. I want to invest in one keyboard that works on my desktop computer but also on other (mobile) devices.

To summaries, I'm looking for a modern, good looking wireless keyboard, that has a good quality feeling. So far hard to find.

[image: Logitech keybord K740]

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right-it is very very hard to find the right keyboard for everything, but if you want to switch between 3 bluetooth devices at the press of a key in the dark and don't need a full size keyboard, the [Logitech K810](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/bluetooth-illuminated-keyboard-k810) seems to be the only one. Tried it in store and was very happy with the build quality but it goes for ~€100.

Another option for fast Bluetooth switching between 3 devices is the [Logitech K480](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/multi-device-keyboard-k480). The keyboard is not illuminated but has a dock to place phones and tablets which is very handy. Again tried it in store and was happy with quality, real shame it's not illuminated. ~€50-55.

For a basic multiple Bluetooth connected keyboard with no illumination or dock there's the [Logitech K 380](https://secure.logitech.com/en-us/product/multi-device-keyboard-k380) for €35-40. Haven't physically touched this.

Hope the K810 is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Bluetooth wise they are all perfect but full size is my number one feature. Maybe I should have made it more clear. These little (portable) keyboards may work fine for some work on the go, but that's not what I'm looking for. Instead "Full sized professional productive developer wireless desktop keyboard" is my goal.